# What is log4j framework?

Tags: java, file, logging, log4j

Can anyone please describe about what is log4j?I go through many tutorials,but all are complicated to understand.Can anyone provide a simple explanation?
log4j.properties

## Define the root logger with appender X

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, X

# Set the appender named X to be a File appender
log4j.appender.X=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

# Define the layout for X appender
log4j.appender.X.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.X.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

I am reading a lot of datas and stored in to db.at that time i am getting heap space error inside my console.To resolve that i have to write into a file...Can i use this framework for my task?

Please also describe the above file also(log4j.properties)

Comment: log4j is a framework for logging diagnostic messages. If you search Google for "[what is log4j?](http://bit.ly/1zEMtzw)" then you'll get plenty of results.

Comment: Log4j is a logging framework. No you can not use it for that.

Answer (score 5):

log4j is a java framework/package used to do application logging of java applications.

It has 3 basic components loggers, appenders, and layouts which are used to serve the purpose of logging in a systematic manner.

To get a basic idea of log4j, you can refer to [this](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) link.

Log4j gives you the freedom to provide configurations in various ways, using either log4j.properties file ([example](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/)) or using log4j.xml file ([example](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-xml-example/))

Answer (score 1):

log4j 'Log For Java', the name says it all.
It's a tool to add logging to your application. You'll need to add some configuration, stating which file you want to use, the log levels (you can only log error logs, informational logs, debug logs, ... So, yes, it is exactly something you can use to achieve this.

But, Log4J isn't the newest tool to do this, there are newer ways (SLF4J, for instance). If you are only implementing it now, it might be worth considering using a newer tool.

Answer (score 1):

Log4j is a framework for **recording** log messages (or "events" as they are called).  Typically, it does this by **writing** them to files.

> I am reading a lot of datas and stored in to db.at that time i am getting heap space error inside my console.To resolve that i have to write into a file...Can i use this framework for my task?

No.

(You could use it *in* your application, but it won't provide functionality you need for reading data and storing it in a database.  And it won't address your heap space issue.)

---

> Please also describe the above file also(log4j.properties)

Refer to the Log4j documentation.  (Perhaps you need to find someone who can translate it into your native language?)